# use CSS to continue overflow list to next column of parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Basically I have a parent Container `<div>` and then I have children elements in there that are aligned using `display: flex;flex-direction:column;flex-wrap:wrap;`.  So far the desired layout is that the container has a fixed height and will scroll to the right as more and more content gets added to he children elements .

All of the children elements will have a fixed width and get stacked in Columns starting in the top left going down then the next row to the right top to bottom.

I have all this working correctly so far , My problem is...

What if one of the children elements is a `<ul>` and lets say that now this new list has `<li>` that overflow their parent.  What happens is that the `<ul>` will grow in height and then will be moved over to the next column.  I do not want that to happen.  I want the `<ul>` to start just where it normally would if it wasn't overflowing and then somehow I am looking for a way for the children `<li>` elements to move to the next row of the lists' Container all the way up at the top like my image that I drew in MS Paint - not the best visual aid - sorry[image]

I also tried to re-create a [stripped down version in a fiddle right here](https://jsfiddle.net/p5m881p4/4/)

This is code from fiddle that creates just a very basic container with come children that show the "problem" or I should say just un-desired results that are currently happening

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <p class="text child"> </p>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>uno</li>
    <li>doce</li>
    <li>tries</li>
    <li>quatro</li>
    <li>sinco</li>
    <li>siete</li>
    <li>ocho</li>
    <li>nueve</li>
    <li>doce</li>
    <li>tries</li>
    <li>quatro</li>
    <li>sinco</li>
    <li>siete</li>
    <li>ocho</li>
    <li>nueve</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.container{border:2px solid blue; width:1000px; height:350px; display:flex; 
       flex-direction:column;flex-wrap:wrap; position:relative;padding:3px;} 

.text{ height:75px;width:200px;border:2px dotted red;display:inline-block; }

.list{flex-wrap:wrap;flex-direction:column;display:flex;width:165px;height:75px;
   border:2 px dashed purple;}

.list li{;flew-wrap:wrap;display:flex;width:200px}

.container div{height:100px;width:200px;border:2px dotted green;display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try using `columns`/`-webkit-columns`**:

```
.container [
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5m881p4/7/).

Comment: you got me really excited , you solution does appear to be perfect , but... your solution is actually splitting the content into 3 columns whether there is over flow or not , you can have 3 letters and that style with split the three letters into 3 columns , That was ssoooooooooo close , but still not at all what I want

Comment: Ok, then you can try using `orphans: 1`, then use `display: inline-block` on the elements.  Also, you can just use media queries on the approach above.  Probably `display: flex` is best with media queries, though.